# SCCM deployment status success despite failure

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012-r2

I have a package that points to a Powershell script which runs the installation steps.  The script fails and returns 1; however, SCCM shows the deployment was successful.

How do I get SCCM to recognize that the script returned an error code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Added [System.Environment] to the end of the script

```
$installresult = (Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c $PSScriptRoot\Configuration\PostConfig.cmd" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
[System.Environment]::Exit($installresult)
```